# VBA - Erro 13 type mismatch for simple coloring labels

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to color 14 labels -- Label1, Label2, Label3,....,Label14.  But getting a Type Mismatch error for my code below...  why?

```
Option Explicit

Private Const BackGrayPastel = 12832724
Private Const BackBlueIce = 14085355
Private Const BackChampagneMedium = 15984043
Private Const BackSnowCone = 11587026
Private Const BackSnowGoose = 14346730
Private Const BackSnowWite = 15922930
Private Const BackSnowDrift = 15326954
Private Const BackPinkCameo = 15711180
Private Const BackPinkMillenial = 16440029
Private Const BackRoseQuartz = 16239305
Private Const BackPurleBlueLight = 9611473
Private Const BackPurpleMedium = 1598786559
Private Const BackSalmon = 3868888575#


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim colorList As Range

    Sheets("ColorCells").Select
    Set colorList = Range("A1:A14")    '<<<< 14 colors in 14 cells

    For r = 1 To 14
       With UserForm1
         .Controls("Label" & r).BackColor = Range("A1").Offset(r, 0).Value   '<<<< There are 14 labels Label1, Label2, Label3,...Label14
       End With
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Range without worksheet specifying is referred to current active object. If it is not worksheet (it is a form in your case it seems) than the error occures. Use direct sheet specifying (`Set colorList = Sheets("ColorCells").Range("A1:A14")`) or `With Sheets("ColorCells")` block. You may use `Sheets("ColorCells").Activate`, of course, but this will move the sheet over the form. Or fail if the form is modal.

Comment: PS. You don't use `colorList` variable somewhere except assign - so it is excess.

Comment: .BackColor likely only takes an RGB value.

Comment: Thank you very much, everyone!  I learned something new!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution.

Define collection for colors. Fill it while form init. Like:

```
' Define private collection for colors
Private Colors As New Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
' Fill colors collection
Colors.Add 12832724, "BackGrayPastel"
Colors.Add 14085355, "BackBlueIce"
Colors.Add 15984043, "BackChampagneMedium"
Colors.Add 11587026, "BackSnowCone"
Colors.Add 14346730, "BackSnowGoose"
Colors.Add 15922930, "BackSnowWite"
Colors.Add 15326954, "BackSnowDrift"
Colors.Add 15711180, "BackPinkCameo"
Colors.Add 16440029, "BackPinkMillenial"
Colors.Add 16239305, "BackRoseQuartz"
Colors.Add 9611473, "BackPurleBlueLight"
Colors.Add 1598786559, "BackPurpleMedium"
Colors.Add 3868888575#, "BackSalmon"

Dim i As Integer, Color As Long
' Iterate colors collection, paint labels
For Each Color In Colors
    i = i + 1
    Me.Controls("Label" & i).BackColor = Color
Next

End Sub
```

If colors names/codes must be read from a worksheet - do it instead of direct assign.

You may refer to colors codes by their names in this form's module using:

```
Colors("color_name")
' or
Colors!color_name
```

Comment: Done, thank you very much Akina!!